# Numeric-type attributes for symbols (analog of NumericFunction)

Tags: symbols, attributes

Is there an attribute for symbols that makes `NumericQ` give `True`?  For example `Pi` and `E` are symbols that behave this way, but I can't figure out which attribute to give it.

`NumericFunction` works well provided the symbol takes at least one argument:

```
SetAttributes[f,NumericFunction]


NumericQ[f]
(*False   <--- I want this to be true*)

NumericQ[f[1]]
(*True*)
```

But I need something for just symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the official way to do it, but at least in 8.0.0.0 you can simply assign it:

```
NumericQ[f] = True
```

For example:

```
N[twopi, n_] := N[2*Pi, n]
NumericQ[twopi] = True
{twopi, twopi > 1}
(*
==> {twopi, True}
*)
```